# Why should we assign the head to a word as early as possible in shift-reduce dependency parsing?

Tags: computational-linguistics, syntax-trees, parsing

This is about dependency parsing. The operation set of a shift-reduce parser was changed so that an arc is added as early as possible. It's claimed that "the longer a word has to wait to get assigned its head, the more opportunities there are for something to go awry." Why?

[image]

Comment: This isn’t a problem of dependency grammar but of a particular algorithm. In general, only non-deterministic parsing can be accurate. The rule you mention is just an heuristic so it’s basically empirical.